# Cutomize TextSelection menu and click event in react natve <Text/> or <HtmlView/>

Tags: android, react-native

screenshot of the view where i  want to add custom menu to select text and save in my db

[image]

Comment: Do you refer to create your own ContextMenu? [**Link Refer**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#context-menu)

Comment: how i can implement in react native

Comment: I think you could check some links with information about ContextMenu in React Native [***Link ContextualMenu in React Native***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=react+native+contextual+menu&oq=react+native+context&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.8735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: it not works on text selection